Proving Extreme points in a convex set are not convex combinations.
If S is convex set. Prove that a point $u$ in S is an extreme point of S if and only if $u$ is not a convex combination of other points of S.
I need to prove that a point $u$ is an extreme point iff it's not a convex combination of other points in $S$. This what I have come up with so far :
Let us suppose that $u$ is an extreme point in $S$ such that
$$u = \sum_{i = 1}^{k} \, c_ix_i$$
Where $c_i \geq 0$ and $\sum_{i = 1}^{k} \, c_i = 1$
Then $u = c_1x_1 + c_2x_2 + \ldots + c_kx_k$
Let us assume that $c_k \neq 0$ then,
\begin{align}
u &= \sum_{i =1}^{k} \, c_ix_i
  &= \sum_{i=1}^{k-1} \, \frac{(1-c_k)c_ix_i}{(1-c_k)}+ c_kx_k
\end{align}
$$u = (1-c_k)\sum_{i=1}^{k-1} \, \frac{c_ix_i}{(1-c_k)} + c_kx_k$$
Where $0<c_k<1$
$\Rightarrow$ $u$ is an interior point of the line segment joining $\sum_{i=1}^{k-1} \, \frac{c_ix_i}{(1-c_k)}$ and $x_k$. Contradiction.
The proof in itself seems fine but it implicitly assumes that $\sum_{i=1}^{k-1} \, \frac{c_ix_i}{(1- c_k)} \, \, \in S$
For which I think the set of all convex combinations of points in $S$ should be a subset of $S$.
What should I do?
Is the proof wrong? Should I prove the aforementioned statement first? Is there another way to prove this?

Extreme point means in the boundary ? If so you must require strictly convex no? And you can simplify your proof by only using a convex combination of two elements

Don't extreme points are defined that way? They are not interior points no? Just endpoints. Doesn't a strictly convex set exclude flat boundaries and corners?

Yes that’s the point.

I'm afraid I am unable to comprehend what your point is. Could you please elaborate?

I thought what you commented is a given when considering a convex combination. How does it relate to the proof?

What is your definition of extreme point ?
